# Finding the array indices of three specific headers

Tags: java, performance, array, comparative-review

I'm considering how to refactor code to make it clean & clear.

There are some principles to make code clean; in this case I think it's **Single Responsibility** and **One level of abstraction**.

The original code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
  if (header[i].equals(Constant.ID)) {
    indexOfID = i;
  } else if (header[i].equals(Constant.NAME)) {
    indexOfName = i;
  } else if (header[i].equals(Constant.CATEGORY)) {
    indexOfCategory = i;
  }
}
```

Then I separated the loop into smaller functions.

```
private int getIndexOfColumnType(String[] header, String type) {
  int index = -1;
  int i = 0;
  int size = header.length;

  while (index < size && index < 0) {
    if(header[i].equals(type)) {
      index = i;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return index;
}
```

And call it

```
int indexOfID = getIndexOfColumnType(header, Constant.ID);
int indexOfName = getIndexOfColumnType(header, Constant.NAME);
int indexOfCategory = getIndexOfColumnType(header, Constant.CATEGORY);
```

In this way, I need to use 3 loops; so I wonder which is better for performance
because `header` array can be large.

Please tell me your idea.

Comment: I'd also want to see a lot more code.  For example, where is `header` populated?

Comment: when ever you need an `if` in your code you most likey should better use polymorphism to solve the situation. But the code you posted is way too short to give a concrete proposal.

Comment: This is small piece of code in a function I extract from my project. The `header` is header of CSV file, so the size can be 2, 3 to ~100.

Answer (score 1):

Both one-for-loop and `getIndexOfColumnType`solutions represent a naive approach: its main drawback is that for each index you need a dedicated variable like `indexOfID` or `indexOfName`.

Since you confirm that the `header` array can be quite large, this also means that you'll need as many variables for indices as there are items in the array.

Of course, there might be more flexible solutions and I see that the first step is already in the original code, supposing that `Constant` is an enumeration like this:

```
public enum Constant {
  ID,
  NAME,
  CATEGORY;
}
```

The index of each column can be mapped with a dedicated [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

```
Map<Constant, Integer> indices = new EnumMap<>(Constant.class);
```

Now this map can be filled with the indices, using a single loop and they will be accessible by the references to the respective `Constant`s:

```
private void calculateColumnIndices() {
  for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    try {
      Constant column = Constant.valueOf(header[i]);
      indices.put(column, i);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      // handle the exception depending on what you expect to do if the header contains an invalid column name
      // TODO
    }
  }
}
```

To access the index:

```
int index = indices.get(Constant.CATEGORY);
```

P.S. I'd also suggest to rename `Constant` to something more meaningful, e.g. `ColumnName`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But in my case `Constant` is Class, which contain common value (not only column name), not an `Enum`. So, how to improve the code?

Comment: You can always create this `enum` without changing/breaking the existing class. Or even use a `Map<String, Integer>`, but enum is obviously better for this case.